# compare values of one column with values of multiple other columns

Tags: r

I have one column (VariableA) of unique IDs that I want to compare with multiple columns (VariableB, VariableC...).

Each column has unique IDs but an ID may be in two or more columns like so:

`VariableA    VariableB    VariableC
0001           0001         0008
0002           0003         0001
0004           0004         0002
0005           0006
0007             NA`

I was using `ainb <- variablea[,1] %in% variableb[,1]` to check whether or not values in VariableA existed in VariableB, which worked, but I cannot search figure out how to get a count of values in VariableA that exist in more than one column (VariableB, VariableC, etc).

Using `ainall <- variablea[,1] %in% dat[,2:6]` just gave me all FALSE. I believe the problem may be that the length of the columns are all different. I'm not trying to match by row, just each individual value.

Hope that's clear enough! Any help appreciated.

Comment: try getting a table count of the other columns and subsetting by the first column like `table(unlist(df[-1]))[df$VariableA]`. What is the name of the data frame? Because this expression shouldn't work `variablea[,1]`. For one, it is not the name of your column and two, the column itself doesn't have two dimensions.

Comment: variablea is the name of a data.frame with just one column (all the IDs of variable a). dat is a data.frame with all of my columns in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example. First, let's create an example data frame:

```
data_example <- data.frame(var_a = 1:10, var_b = c(1:5,11:15), var_c=c(1:7, NA, NA, NA))
> data_example
   var_a var_b var_c
1      1     1     1
2      2     2     2
3      3     3     3
4      4     4     4
5      5     5     5
6      6    11     6
7      7    12     7
8      8    13    NA
9      9    14    NA
10    10    15    NA
```

So you can see that `var_a` overlaps with `var_b` by 50%, and `var_c` by 70% (and `var_c` has some NAs).

Let's see which unique values overlap, for each column:

```
overlap_vals = apply(data_example, 2, intersect, data_example$var_a)
> overlap_vals
$var_a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$var_b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$var_c
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Now we want to know how many elements of `var_a` appear in these overlap vectors. Start by creating a little helper function that gets the proportion overlap for one vector in the list:

```
propn_overlap <- function(comparison_vector, id_vector){ 
                     sum(id_vector %in% comparison_vector) / length(id_vector)
                 }
```

Now we can use sapply to apply our helper function over all the vectors in the list:

```
> sapply(overlap_vals, propn_overlap, data_example$var_a)
var_a var_b var_c 
  1.0   0.5   0.7
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, I'm definitely keeping these functions in memory. Thank you so much!